# React Apollo Component props in `options.update` method

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

guys, need your help

I have the following question:

Imagine, we have a blog website. We have an author page with lists of posts he created `/author/:authorId`. And author wants to add another post to the end of this list.
We have a mutation for this:

```
mutation PostCreateMutation($id: ID!, $title: String!) {
    createPost(id: $id, title: $title, text: $text) { … }
}
```

And after the mutation is called, i want to update UI without refetching all posts. I cannot use `options.update` method, because my update function looks like this:

```
update: (proxy, { data: { createPost } }) => {
    const data = proxy.readQuery({
        query: AUTHOR_QUERY,
        variables: {
            id: ‘1’ // => i cant get authorId here =(
        }
    });
}
```

I cant get `authorId` in `update` method, because I don't have an access to component props there… How should i handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apollo, `options` [can be a function instead of an object](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#options-from-props). So the config object you pass to your HOC can look like this:

```
{
  options: ({authorId}) => ({
    update: (proxy, { data: { createPost } }) => {
        const data = proxy.readQuery({
            query: AUTHOR_QUERY,
            variables: {
                id: authorId,
            }
        });
    }
  }),
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try and post here = )